# Org-Mode Inline Code with Equals Signs

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, I want to give inline code with equals signs and quotation marks:

```
<div class="foo">
```

The way I would normally do this in org-mode is

```
=<div class="foo">=
```

When I export this to HTML, it gets rendered like this:

`<div class`"foo">=

What is the right way to do this inline (rather than just creating a source block)?

Answer (score 16):

You could use verbatim markers, `~`, instead:

```
~<div class="foo">~
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it seems like if the thing I'm specifying is code, I should be able to mark that it's code!

Comment: According to [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html), `~` is a code marker. Did they change it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the equals sign after 'class' is interpreted as the closing code section delimiter. You can prevent this by inserting a space before the equals sign, like this:

```
=<div class = "foo">=
```

Comment: This is a frustratingly effective workaround.  I won't accept it though, because if spaces were actually important in the code, it would no longer be effective, so it's not really a "solution".

Comment: I think you can do it by modifying org-emphasis-regexp-components, but I'm too lazy to try. See http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html and 'C-h v org-emphasis-regexp-components RET'

Answer (score 2):

After almost a decade, here's the correct answer:

Org's [escape character](https://orgmode.org/manual/Escape-Character.html) is [zero width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space). When this character is inserted, Emacs will not interpret `=` as the end of the verbatim. Emacs can correctly interpret `=<div class​="foo">=`. Note that this string has an invisible zero width space character.

However, I think due to a bug, exports from org to other formats, will have this character and need to be removed manually. For example, the export of the string above to markdown will be `` `<div class​="foo">` `` which is what we want, except that it has an additional zero width space character.
It is not very hard to fix this. Removing all these additional characters can be easily done with `replace-string` command.

Tip: You can use `C-x 8 RET` (or `insert-char` command) and choose `200B` to insert zero width space character inside Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted org-mode's source code to appear correctly in Github's parser. But, just as `=:echo "hello"=` would not appear correctly in Emacs, it also did not appear correctly in Github. However, I tried other characters with `C-x 8 RET`, and the `LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` and `RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` work. That is,

```
=:echo “hello“=
```

appear successfully as

```
:echo “hello“
```

Unfortunately, I don't think they will actually work if copy-and-pasted into all environments. Vim gives `E15: Invalid expression: “hello“`. But then, how often do we paste commands into Vim's command line. Well, okay, there is `:@"`.